# How do I read a bytearray from a CSV file using pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a `csv` file which has a column full of `bytearrays`. It looks like this:

```
bytearray(b'\xf3\x90\x02\xff\xff\xff\xe0?')
bytearray(b'\xf3\x90\x02\xff\xff\xff\xe0?')
bytearray(b'\xf3\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xe0?')
```

and so on. I tried to read this `csv` file using `pandas.read_csv()`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False)
data = df.msg
```

`msg` is the name of the column with the bytearrays.

But it doesn't look like this is a column full of bytearrays. When I pick out a column and try to print individual elements with `print(data[1][1])`, the output I get is `y`, which corresponds to the `1` position in `bytearray`.

How can I import this particular column as a list of bytearrays?

Comment: is the text in the file literally: `bytearray(b'\xf3\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xe0?')`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a converter function to `pandas.read_csv()` to turn your `bytearray` into a `bytearray`

**Code:**

```
from ast import literal_eval

def read_byte_arrays(bytearray_string):
    if bytearray_string.startswith('bytearray(') and \
            bytearray_string.endswith(')'):
        return bytearray(literal_eval(bytearray_string[10:-1]))
    return bytearray_string
```

**Test Code:**

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(u'\n'.join([x.strip() for x in r"""
    data1,bytes,data2
    1,bytearray(b'\xf3\x90\x02\xff\xff\xff\xe0?'),2
    1,bytearray(b'\xf3\x90\x02\xff\xff\xff\xe0?'),2
    1,bytearray(b'\xf3\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xe0?'),2
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]))

df = pd.read_csv(data, converters={'bytes': read_byte_arrays})
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
   data1                                  bytes  data2
0      1  [243, 144, 2, 255, 255, 255, 224, 63]      2
1      1  [243, 144, 2, 255, 255, 255, 224, 63]      2
2      1    [243, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 224, 63]      2
```